# An internal error occurred during: "Java Search". -1

Tags: java, eclipse, search

When does the below error is thrown in Eclipse -

`An internal error occurred during: "Java Search".
-1`

I tried to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> on a method to find from where it is getting called. Which appears to be working fine but with the above error.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if you have duplicate entries in classpath.

The solution which mostly works to get rid of this error is to delete the project from eclipse and them reimport it as existing project.